# The meaning of an explanatory variable in computing accuracy of a prediction model (migrated to CrossValidated)

Tags: r, prediction, tidymodels

I am following the predictive modeling example found [here](https://mdsr-book.github.io/mdsr2e/ch-modeling.html), chapter 10.

This piece of the code has `capital_gain` as the explanatory variable, but removing it or replacing it with another variable doesn't change anything in the output. The estimate and confusion matrix remain the same. So why is `capital_gain` there in that place?

```
library(yardstick)
pred <- train %>%
  select(income, capital_gain) %>% #why 'capital_gain' is here? 
  bind_cols(
    predict(mod_null, new_data = train, type = "class")
  ) %>%
  rename(income_null = .pred_class)
accuracy(pred, income, income_null)


confusion_null <- pred %>%
  conf_mat(truth = income, estimate = income_null)
confusion_null
```

EDIT: path to the data used -> http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data

EDIT: this post is migrated to CrossValidated

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "does not change anything in the output" and "the estimate remains the same"? Does the predicted probability for each class actually remain the same when you omit *capital_gain*?

Answer (score 1):

You do not explain what your data is (something form the `yardstick` package?), but the situation that omitting a predictor varaible does not change the predictions of a linear model typically occurs when you have multi-collinearity in your data. In this case, any of the collinear variables can be omitted without losing predicton accuracy.

You can test for *exact* mutli-collinearity in your data by checking whether the rank of your predictor matrix is equal to the number of independent variables. If not, you have exact collinearity:

```
> A <- cbind(iris[,-5], 2*iris[,1]+iris[,2])
> ncol(A)
[1] 5
> qr(A)$rank
[1] 4
```

If there is only approximate collinearity, you can compute the "variance inflation factor" (VIF) of your variables. High values indicate (say greater than 5) multi-collinearity. VIF implementations do not come with vanilla R, but there are many packages that implement it.

Comment: I'm not sure that the question says that " does not change the predictions ". They only seem to be looking at the accuracy and confusion matrix. Perhaps they can clarify.

Comment: @user20650 Good point! I will ask for clarification.

Comment: @user20650 exactly, I'm only looking at the accuracy and confusion matrix

Comment: @Gato ; thanks. They are not the best measures for evaluating the predictive ability of a variable but I think that these questions are better placed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user20650; We are missing the issue here. I think this is not about measuring the predictive ability of a variable, but a model. I don't prefectly understand why the variable ```capital_gain``` is placed where it is. Removing it affects to the prediction model (logistic regression) output, but apparently just a little bit. The difference can be visually seen when comparing scatter plots of the model, with or without ```capital_gain``` in the piece of code in my post

Comment: @Gato So you are using logistic regression, which is an important information. In this case it would be useful to check for mutli-collinearity, because it can lead to the weird situation that *all* estimated predictor coefficients are reported as not significantly different from zero. Is `capital_gain` reported as "significant" (check the p-value in `summary(fit)`)? As this is not an R question, but a statistics question, the question should be migrated to CrossValidated. You must provide more information in the question, however, because otherwise noone will be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks @cdalitz, I'll migrate this post to CrossValidated